# Bad Certificate SSL exception while trying to access https url

Tags: java

I have a piece of code to download an excel from online and save it in the desired location. I have run the code in local
(run as "Java Application") it works perfectly fine. But when I added it in the project code and deployed it in weblogic 10.3
it gets stuck after the authentication. Could you please help me out here.

```
public void saveFileFromUrlWithJavaIO(String fileName, String fileUrl) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
WEBLOGGER.info("Going into this method...");
BufferedInputStream in = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
WEBLOGGER.info("Going into this method...");
try {
WEBLOGGER.info("trying to authenticate...");
authenticate();
WEBLOGGER.info("Authentication done...");
in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileUrl).openStream());
WEBLOGGER.info("in operation done...");
fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
WEBLOGGER.info("Going into this method...");
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
WEBLOGGER.info("Going into this method...");
while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
fout.write(data, 0, count);
}
} finally {
if (in != null)
in.close();
if (fout != null)
fout.close();
}
}
```

I get the following error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.
```

After some digging, I have enabled Use `JSSE SSL` in weblogic server console. Now I get the following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

Comment: you have problem with `new URL(fileUrl).openStream()`, first sysout `fileUrl` and add `catch` block.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Try adding catch block and print the stacktrace.

Comment: Looks like your fileUrl points to a HTTPS endpoint

Comment: Yes..It is a https url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the authentication and proxy handling contents in the code and made following changes in the weblogic console.

```
1)
In setEnv file located in your weblogic server path(i.e /apps/appName/bin) added:
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dhttps.proxyHost=x.y.z"
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dhttps.proxyPort=port"
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=*.y.z"

2) In weblogic console: servers-> keystores Change from “Demo identity and Demo trust” to “Custom Identity
and Java Standard Trust”

3) in weblogic console: servers-> SSL-> advanced-> Tick “Use JSSE SSL” and also set “Hostname Verification” to
none
```

Useful link: `http://www.ateam-oracle.com/improve-ssl-support-for-your-weblogic-domains/`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. And solved with one step:

On weblogic console: servers-> SSL-> advanced-> Enable “Use JSSE SSL”.

Reading the documentation of the weblogic version I am using ([10.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13707/ssl.htm#SECMG386)), I believe this problem occurs that the default implementation of SSL supports an small amount of protocols... according to this:

> If JSSE is enabled, this property value enables any protocol starting with "TLS" for messages that are sent and accepted; for example, TLS V1.0, TLS V1.1, and TLS V1.2. If the Certicom-based SSL implementation is enabled, only TLS V1 is enabled.